# Google Custom Search API returning invalid JSON?

Tags: node.js, google-search-api

I'm calling Google Custom Search w/ Node.js to try.  I'm getting results back just fine, but when I try and parse the JSON using JSON.parse(dataFromGoogle), I get illegal token errors on a number of elements (html titles and snippets; the html titles have unicode escape sequences in them, but I'm not sure what's wrong w/ the snippets).  I can have Google not send me back the html titles, but I really need the snippets!

Is there a good work-around on this, or should I just plan on doing some additional preprocessing to strip out illegal characters manually?

**** Edit: added console output from this

searching for "small business" using Google

> {
>    "kind": "customsearch#search",
>    "url": {
>     "type": "application/json",
>     "template": "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q={searchTerms}&num={count?}&start={startIndex?}&hr={language?}&safe={safe?}&cx={cx?}&cref={cref?}&sort={sort?}&filter={filter?}&gl={gl?}&cr={cr?}&googlehost={googleHost?}&alt=json"
>    },
>    "queries": {
>     "nextPage": [
>      {
>       "title": "Google Custom Search - small business",
>       "totalResults": "42300",
>       "searchTerms": "small business",
>       "count": 10,
>       "startIndex": 11,
>       "inputEncoding": "utf8",
>       "outputEncoding": "utf8",
>       "safe": "off",
>       "cx": "my_token"
>      }
>     ],
>     "request": [
>      {
>       "title": "Google Custom Search - small business",
>       "totalResults": "42300",
>       "searchTerms": "small business",
>       "count": 10,
>       "startIndex": 1,
>       "inputEncoding": "utf8",
>       "outputEncoding": "utf8",
>       "safe": "off",
>       "cx": "my_token"
>      }
>     ]
>    },
>    "context": {
>     "title": "IR
>   undefined:60
>      "htmlTitle": "\u003cb\u003eSmall Business\u003c/b\u003e Health Care Tax Cre
>                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
>       at Object.parse (native)
>       at IncomingMessage. (/Users/pvencill/workspace/irslab/lib/searchEngine.js:44:35)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:64:17)
>       at HTTPParser.onBody (http.js:119:42)
>       at CleartextStream.ondata (http.js:1213:22)
>       at CleartextStream._push (tls.js:291:27)
>       at SecurePair._cycle (tls.js:565:20)
>       at EncryptedStream.write (tls.js:97:13)
>       at Socket.ondata (stream.js:40:26)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:64:17)

Comment: What does their response look like?

Comment: It's proper JSON except for the fact that it includes unicode escapes in some of the fields.  I filtered out those fields as a temporary fix, but eventually I'd like to have them.  I'll post tomorrow what I had, I was doing it on my work machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, so it turns out I totally misunderstood what the error was telling me.  The fact that it was happening on unicode-containing fields was coincidence.  The *real* issue was that I was calling JSON.parse inside the .on("data", ...) handler, which is handling part of the chunked response; might not be valid JS statement terminator before the chunk completes.  The proper way to handle it is to build the body and then use on("end") to parse it.

```
        var message = "";
        https.get(options, function(res){
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', function(data){
                message += data;
            });

            res.on('end', function(){
                if(callback){
                    var data = JSON.parse(message);
                    data.items = data.items || [];
                    callback(data);
                }
            });

            res.on('error', function(error){
                console.log("ERROR" + error.message);
            });
```

Comment: Nice.  Wouldn't have guessed that.